# functions before handlers spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Im new in Spring and in frameworks in general ...

I have some lines of code I want to execute in almost every handler.
For example I save my DB session and the authenticated user as httpSession attributes and for most of my handlers I have:

```
@RequestMapping(....)
public ModelAndView get(HttpSession ses){
   User u = ses.getAttribute("currUser");
   DBsession session = ses.getAttribute("DBsession");
   if( u==null ) new ModelAndView("redirect:login");
   ...
}
```

Is there any way for spring to do that for me and get the DBsession and authenticated User objects directly as handler param ?

```
@RequestMapping(....)
public ModelAndView get(User u, DBsession session ){
   ...
}
```

Comment: You mean like an interceptor or filter?

Comment: @Dave maybe but Im not sure ... are there any links with examples?

Comment: @Jesse my dbsession isn't a request param, it's an object generated every time an httpSession is created ... nothing to do with requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use a custom [WebArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html), which cleanly extends `@RequestMapping` annotated handler methods to resolve parameters. I used this mechanism to handle cleanly merging JPA entities and passing them to my controllers.

You can see an example of doing this [here](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2009/10/23/custom-arguments-for-requestmapping-methods/) and [here](http://karthikg.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/learn-to-customize-spring-mvc-controller-method-arguments/) or Google for more, there are plenty.

Comment: Nice one thanks! This will solve most of the 'problem' by passing 'ready to use' args ... The other part (to complete the 'request preprocessing') is redirecting to login page for non-authenticated Users. Any solution for that?

Comment: For this you will probably want to use a servlet filter or Spring interceptor depending on your exact requirements, which is completely separate to the piece I described here. They are really distinct questions in my mind, each with using different techniques to solve. For authentication etc. personally I tend to favour Spring Security unless there is a compelling reason not to use it.

Comment: Seems I have lots of stuff to learn :p ... Any good links for spring security, servlet filter and interceptors will be appreciated ...